# Entity Framework Core with managed identity to Azure SQL gives Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

We've enabled managed identity to connect to our Identity Server database on Azure using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) but get the following error after a while (~7 hours).

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnection
PoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](IEnumerable`1 results, QueryContext queryContext, IList`1 entityTrackingInfos, IList`1 entityAccessors)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore.GetAllResourcesAsync()
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.IResourceStoreExtensions.GetAllEnabledResourcesAsync(IResourceStore store)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.DiscoveryResponseGenerator.CreateDiscoveryDocumentAsync(String baseUrl, String issuerUri)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Connection string:
`Data Source=tcp:{sqlServerUrl},1433;Initial Catalog={databaseName};`

```cs
var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    })

    // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources, CORS)
    .AddConfigurationStore(configureStoreOptions =>
    {
        // uses the MSI to connect to SQL.
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).
            GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;

        configureStoreOptions.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(
                conn,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
)
```

Comment: You mean it worked fine at first but got an error after a while?

Comment: Yep, after a couple of hours it returns this error on for example the `/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint

Comment: The server is closing the connection when it is idle or after a long period of time.

Comment: The error says that it cannot connect to your database as an anonymous user. This is unrelated to your Identity setup. You will need to fix your connection string to the database to provide the correct information necessary.

Comment: Connection string is OK, it works after a restart, after a couple of hours the error shows.

Comment: It looks like your SqlConnection.AccessToken expires, but MS interprets it as an anonymous logon.

Comment: @Luuk could you update your question to be better searchable: I suggested the title: "Entity Framework Core with managed identity to Azure SQL gives Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' after a while" and tags: "sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4, entity-framework-core", but the system blocks my edit as I don't have 2K rep, and the question contains too much code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation creates a connection once, and in an hour the token expires.

A solution is to move the connection initializer inside the Configure function:

```
.AddConfigurationStore(configureStoreOptions =>
{
    configureStoreOptions.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
    {
      // uses the MSI to connect to SQL.
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).
          GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
      builder.UseSqlServer(
            conn,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    }
})
```